# ListView do not autoscroll to selected item if its position changed

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, .net-3.5

I have a ListView with about 100 items. I have some item selected from past and now I need to scroll down to find another item, but in that time - refresh occurs and it just automatically scroll back to last selected item.

Is there any possibility how can I turn it off or better dont scroll if I'm currently scrolling?

Thanks for responds :)

Comment: If you can find the BeginScroll/EndScroll event, you can just stick BeginUpdate and EndUpdate in each respective method.

Comment: @ofstream there is no BeginScroll/EndScroll neither any event with Scroll in name :/

Comment: I think we would need to know what you are doing in your code for the ListView to refresh.   There is probably a different way to handle that part of your code.

Comment: @jross I have a contact list. And if some user change availability, its just resorted - so refresh will occur. And if I'm in this time scrolling it will just move me to position with currently selected contact.

Comment: Can you provide the part of the code that refreshes the list?

Comment: @Dzienny I dont know what you mean. I just call ListBox `Sort` method. If you want to know something specific tell me what.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are allowing the ListView to get updated with new data while the user is using it for an unrelated operation.  Especially since you are Sorting the data in the view.  That might tricky to solve.   In any event if would be helpful for you to post a code snippet that duplicates the problem w/ enough code that makes it clear what the issue is.

Comment: @jross Ok as I understood it will allways do that if ListView is updated. But I'm asking if I can overload some method and capture some message to deny auto-scrolling to selected item. Or if there is any property which can I just set to false. Or is it really so difficult? I just dont want from ListBox control scrolling to selected item like `AutoScrollToSelectedItemOnRefresh = false` or something like that.

Comment: @sczdavos What about just not calling `Sort`?

Comment: Are you calling the Sort() method OR set the Sorting property of the ListView?

Comment: I already know what causes this. Its `Refresh` method which is also called with `Sort` method. And I want sort items. But I dont want scrolling to selected item on refresh. So again, I'm asking if there is any possibility, where can I override it and fxp. capture message to scroll or if there si any property which can deny it.

Comment: I have tried various combinations:  there are several different issues.  For example, it even makes a difference in what “View” mode you are in (LargeIcon I see the problem, in Details I don't see it). Without getting into the Win32 API, I see no way to override the default WinForm behavior. There is the BeginUpdate()and EndUpdate() but I don’t think that is going to help you.

Comment: @jross I'm using `Tile` View. Ok doesn't matter. I'll try look for it deeper.

Comment: Can you use the Details view?  if you can, I can post a code snippet that does not have the problem w/ scrolling back to the selected item.

Comment: @jross I've it optimized for Tiles. But if you can post solution with Details view, I'll try play with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if this will help but here the settings that do NOT have the issue with scrolling back to the selected item when a new item is added and sorted.  However, I use the sort setting and do not call sort or refresh.

Create a new form and place ListView and a Timer on there. On the ListView change ONLY these properties.

- Set View to Details
- Click Columns add a single Column (Adjust the width to make it wider)
- Set Sorting to Ascending
- Set the timer Enabled to true
- Set interval to 2000 (2 secs)
- Double click the Tick event to create a handler

Now add the following code

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add("Item #" + x);
    }
}

private int y = 10;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Add("Item #" + y + "b");
    y += 10;
}
```

Now when you run this you can select any item and scroll anywhere and it will not jump back to the selected item when a new item is added.  However, it will scroll down one line if the item it adds is above …

Perhaps this gets you close enough that you can play with it further to get what you need.

But that is the best I could do w/o getting into sub-classing the ListView Control using the Win32 API somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a roundabout solution (and probably a little late), but it seems to work.
I'm using EnsureVisible() on the most recent added item to have auto-scrolling happen, which is called within the timer1_Tick method.  But I'm using an "inspectingList" flag that will keep auto-scrolling from happening when you click on a list item.  When focus moves away from the listview, scrolling continues as normal.

Part of the solution is what jross said to do, which is create a dummy form to test with:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Columns.Add("Scroll Control", 100);

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(string.Format("Item #{0:000}", i));
        }

        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private int newItem = 10;
    private bool inspectingList = false;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(string.Format("Item #{0:000}", newItem));
        newItem += 10;

        if (!inspectingList)
        {
            listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].EnsureVisible();
        }
        listView1.Refresh();
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectingList = true;
        if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
        {
            listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[0]].EnsureVisible();
        }
    }

    private void listView1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectingList = false;
    }
```